# Plone 4: How to define a Content action url_expr that redirects to objects parent container

Tags: plone

I have a (dexterity) content type that defines the following action.

```
<action title="Search" 
        action_id="search" 
        category="object" 
        condition_expr=""
        url_expr="python:aq_parent(aq_inner(context))" 
        visible="True">
        <permission value="View"/>
</action>
```

`url_expr` contains, what I try to get, but I get a `NameError`. I imported the functions from Acquisition in the corresponding content class, but that did not help.

Any hints? Thanks in advance.

**Update I**

I tried the suggested solution, but that leads to the following trace (urls cropped):

http://pastie.org/6100541

So I switched back to my solution. Bug or feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asking helps!

I got this idea just a few minutes after asking ;)

```
[...]
url_expr="python:'/'.join(object_url.split('/')[0:-1])"
[...]
```

Seems a bit *hacked* to me and in this form does not deal with GET stuff. Any better ideas or recommendations still welcome.

Answer (score 2):

`aq_parent` and `aq_inner` functions are not available there, but you can use:

```
python:context.aq_inner.aq_parent
```

Comment: Hmm, that looked so pretty, but did not work in my case. It's Plone 4.2.1. Maybe its a bug.